# Ocaml how to identify function

Tags: ocaml

I want to write Ocaml function, that takes two parameters: other function (int->int) and int value, and than check somehow if it was used with these to parameters earlier. how to do it?

so other way of looking at that problem is how to identify function with the identification that can be variable?

The problem is: Make function g, that takes functions f and int value n, than check if g was already used for f for that value n, if yes return previously got result, otherwise count f for n value. f is int->int

Comment: May I ask why you need to compare functions?

Comment: I have edited post, so you can see, why i need it. I do not know if it is even good to idea to do it that way, but if not, you can give me better one. I am just programming adept.

Comment: *"count f for n value"* do you mean call `f` with `n` as the parameter?

Comment: It seems you're trying to build a memoization technique for any function `f` of signature `int -> int`. Am I correct?

Comment: yes for both answers in comments above

Comment: `check if g was already used for f for that value n` what does it mean? also what means `count f for n value`. Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: jackson, see didierc response. It should be noted to Michal, that this technique will not memoize recursive calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare functions with the `==` operator.

```
# let f x = x + 2;;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# let g x = x  + 5;;
val g : int -> int = <fun>
# f == g;;
- : bool = false
# f == f;;
- : bool = true
#
```

Using the `==` operator is very dangerous, however. Comparing things for physical equality is inadvisable because it pierces the veil of [referential transparency](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)). I would personally look for another way to solve whatever problem you're working on. (If you'll forgive the suggestion.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to flip your idea around: instead of keeping the function `f` and `g` separately, have `g` turn `f` into a memoizing version of itself:

```
module IntMap = Map.Make (struct type t = int let compare a b = a - b end)

let g f =
    let m = ref (IntMap.empty) in
    fun x -> 
        try IntMap.find x !m
        with Not_found ->
           let r = f x in
           m := IntMap.add x r !m;
           r
```

It's obviously worth doing benchmarks to see if the cost of computation is worse that the one of memoization. Also, it could be better to use a `Hashtbl` instead of a `Map` (left as an exercise).

Comment: Thanks man for answer. Actually idea was to compute f n and find if f n was called in separate threads and idea was that f compute really long, but that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, then perhaps you need to make sure that the memoized data is accessed atomically.

Comment: `find if f n was called in separate threads` I guess you have to really post out the complete problem. In your problem description, too much confusion. If you say `separate threads`, then the possible memorise code needs `Mutex` to lock then.